# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring for some testing, and I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader  at org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest
```

The JAR that I installed is: spring-test-2.5.6.jar

Do I need another jar besides this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also need `spring-core-*.jar.` You can usually tell what jars you are missing by looking at the package. In this org.springframework.core.* is all in the core jar file.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advice using Maven (or Ivy or Gradle) for dependency management. It can save you loads of pain in resolving these types of secondary and tertiary dependencies.

Comment: +1 for maven. I was going to suggest that but I felt that's not what the question was asking.

Answer (score 1):

As per Amir's answer the jar you need is spring-core. You can generally solve this sort of issue by consulting jarfinder http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/search/~org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader~